# Running LISP code via CLISP on Linux (Ubuntu WSL)

Tags: linux, lisp, common-lisp, windows-subsystem-for-linux, clisp

I am new to LISP and was wondering how to correctly run a simple lisp program on Ubuntu Linux. Currently, I have a LISP file called "intmax.lisp" that contains the following code:

`(defun intmax (x y) (if (> x y) x y))`

However, when I go to the command line and run:

`clisp intmax 2 4`

To compare 2 and 4, I get no output. Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: why would `clisp intmax 2 4` work? See https://cliki.net/Online%20Tutorial

Comment: See the manual: https://clisp.sourceforge.io/impnotes/quickstart.html#quickstart-unix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get started, use the REPL.  That is not the shell command line, but rather something like a command line inside of Lisp.

Start the Lisp system:

```
clisp
```

You get a prompt like the following:

```
[1]>
```

Load your file:

```
[1]> (load "intmax.lisp")
```

Now you can call your function:

```
[2]> (intmax 2 4)
```

And it will print:

```
4
```

And prompt again:

```
[3]>
```

You may want to learn about packages and systems later in order to organize your code.

If you want to call things from the command line, you need to tell clisp to load what is needed, then execute a lisp command.  Look at the man page for that.  Example:

```
clisp -q -i intmax.lisp -x '(intmax 2 4)'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `clisp` executable does not translate its arguments into a function call. However, you can make CLISP program which does that. I did exactly such a thing for the licensing back end of a Lisp application. I wanted a simple administrative command language to look up users and grant them licenses and things like that, from the system prompt. So I just wrote a shim which converts the individual command line arguments into Lisp objects gathered into a List and dispatches it as more or less a function.

Let's warm up by making this program, in a file called `clisp-dispatch.lisp`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env clisp
  
(print *args*)
```

When we run it like this, we see that `*args*` provides access to the arguments:

```
$ chmod a+x clisp-dispatch.lisp # give it exec permission
$ ./clisp-dispatch.lisp

NIL
$ ./clisp-dispatch.lisp a b c 1 2 3
("a" "b" "c" "1" "2" "3")
```

Very good. Now what we would like to see is the list `(A B C 1 2 3)`: a list of symbols and numbers, and not a list of character strings. Let's change the code a little bit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env clisp
  
(print (mapcar #'read-from-string *args*))
```

The `read-from-string` function scans a character string using the Lisp reader, returning the Lisp object implied by its syntax. If the syntax looks like a symbol, a symbol is returned; if it is a number, a number is returned and so on. For instance `(read-from-string "(1 2 3"))` yields the list `(1 2 3)`.   With that, we get:

```
$ ./clisp-dispatch.lisp a b c 1 2 3

(A B C 1 2 3)
```

Very good! So all that is left is to treat this list as Lisp code, and to do that we just pass it to the `eval` function. Let's keep in the `print`, but use it for the result of the `eval`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env clisp

(print (eval (mapcar #'read-from-string *args*)))
```

Now we can do:

```
$ ./clisp-dispatch.lisp + 2 2

4 
$ ./clisp-dispatch.lisp list 1 2 3

(1 2 3) 
$ ./clisp-dispatch.lisp cons "'a" 3

(A . 3)
```

So with this, if we define an `intmax` function, we can call it from the system prompt.

```
#!/usr/bin/env clisp

(defun intmax (a b)
  (max a b))

(print (eval (mapcar #'read-from-string *args*)))

$ ./clisp-dispatch.lisp intmax 3 1

3 
$ ./clisp-dispatch.lisp intmax 7 10

10
```

You're probably better off exploring Lisp from within Lisp though, rather than indirectly invoking it from the command line like this. For one thing, every time we run this program, a new Lisp image is started. We are not able to interact with the environment. We also have to use very clumsy quoting for some kinds of syntax, like the way I used `"'a"` to pass through `'a` to Lisp.

What we have done is to use the Lisp in a very particular way that is not supported directly in the `clisp` executable: parsing the arguments like Lisp objects, then treating the result as a function call. And in any case, anyone who wants to "abuse" Lisp like his can just write the above tiny program.

Note also how I defined `intmax`, just by calling `max`. The point is that there is no need to define `intmax` in Common Lisp; the built-in `max` function takes one or more arguments and returns the maximum: `(max 1 3 2)` yields `3`. Because `(int-max x y)` is just `(max x y)`, there is no reason for `int-max` to exist. It's just an impaired synonym for `max` which takes four more characters to type and doesn't take more than two arguments.